# copy(move) several vectors to one vector of struct containing vectors' type

Tags: c++

I have some filled several vectors, like

```
std::vector<int> data1;
std::vector<std::string> data2;
std::vector<customClass> data3;
...
```

I want to put them in the same struct.

```
struct Data{
    int d1;
    std::string d2;
    customClass d3;
    ...
}
std::vector<Data> data_vector;
```

Is there a standard to copy(or move) `data1`, `data2`, `data3` to `data_vector`, and vise versa without looping all `Data`'s element?

```
// sizes are same
// copy for this case

for(int i=0; i<data1.size(); ++i){
    data_vector[i].d1 = data1[i];
    data_vector[i].d2 = data2[i];
    data_vector[i].d3 = data3[i];
    ...
}
```

Something like this

```
copy_jump_memory(data1.begin(), data1.end(), memory_pos(data_vector[0].d1), sizeof(Data));
copy_jump_memory(data2.begin(), data2.end(), memory_pos(data_vector[0].d2), sizeof(Data));
copy_jump_memory(data3.begin(), data3.end(), memory_pos(data_vector[0].d3), sizeof(Data));
...
```

Comment: I don't think there's a standard here.  The closest you would get would be to define your own iterator template that wraps `std::vector<Data>` but dereferences to the desired type via pointer-to-member.  Then use that with `std::copy` in the manner you describe.  But this would not result in useful, readable code.  I think a better approach is to create iterators for each input vector, reserve storage in your output vector, then construct a local `Data` each iterator, call `push_back` with move-semantics, and advance your iterators.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977339/create-vector-of-tuples-from-two-vectors-by-move this one might help, although they were making tuples instead of struct